# restricted attribute for custom templatetag only on production

Tags: python, django, web-applications, beautifulsoup, webfaction

I am using this templatetag:

```
@register.filter
def php_striptags(text, allowed=""):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

    # list all tags
    allowed_tags = allowed.split()

    for tag in soup.find_all(True):
        if tag.name not in allowed_tags:
            tag.unwrap()

    return soup.encode_contents().decode('utf8')
```

It works just fine on development machine but I get this error on production:

```
Exception Type:     RuntimeError
Exception Value:    restricted attribute
Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/inspect.py in getargspec, line 813
```

I am hosting my site on webfaction, running with apache and mod_wsgi. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the real issue, which actually was documented in BeautifulSoup doc:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#other-parser-problems

> If your script works on one computer but not another, it’s probably because the two computers have different parser libraries available. For example, you may have developed the script on a computer that has lxml installed, and then tried to run it on a computer that only has html5lib installed. See Differences between parsers for why this matters, and fix the problem by mentioning a specific parser library in the BeautifulSoup constructor.

So to make your soup, try something like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Just had the same exception on a production server, and this fix worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you did not install BeautifulSoup into your system Python lib, but instead you've downloaded BeautifulSoup, and put it in your custom `PYTHONPATH`. This makes your copy of BeautifulSoup to be considered as an external Python code, and Python runs it in restricted mode (see [Restricted Execution](http://docs.python.org/2/library/restricted.html))

Simply install BeautifulSoup through `pip`/`easy_install`, or install an OS package for it, and this error will go away.